# Audio input: stereo to mono and filtering DC

Tags: capacitor, audio, input, stereo

I have to get an audio input from a PCB 3.5mm jack and summing right and left channel into one (mono). Then, I have to filter any DC noise from the input.

[image]

Resistors are **1kOhm** each. This, for now, work perfectly.
Then i found this circuit in another question on this stack exchange:

[image]

There are two capacitors of **10uF** before the junction to filter the DC current.

Now the questions:

1. The circuit scheme is valid?
2. Capacitors are not polarized?
3. If I want to use a single capacitor after the junction, I have to
   use a 5uF?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes but you can use polarized caps (+ on the left) 3. The value is not critical, anything above a few uF's is fine.

Comment: to be clear, in the second schematic the outputs "Left" and "Right" will be identical and not be the same as the inputs. The output will still be mono sound, not stereo.

Comment: @VladimirCravero  ok thank you, now the last question: can i put the cap after the junction or before on the single channels?

Comment: @JoeS yes, I know, i only answered for the filtering :)

Comment: @Northumber Just making sure! also in my experience the cap can go either before or after the junction.

Comment: btw: you can get 10uf ceramic caps nowadays (unpolarized)

Comment: What is your input source and output load?